# Selenium Webdriver to insert text from python in text area

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<textarea style="font-size: 1.2em" ng-model="applications" ng-list=" " ng-trim="false" rows="15" cols="70" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"></textarea>
```

This is the text area tag. I want to insert some text into the text area. How can I proceed with the python code for the selenium webdriver.

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched")
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Finding an element using angular tags can be a bit flaky. I think the classes like ng-pristine will be removed once the field has changed. A better approach would be to find the field using parent or sibling elements. Also if there is only 1 texteara, you can try: find_element_by_tag_name('textarea')

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched[ng-model='applications']").send_keys("samhith gardas")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched' and @ng-model='applications']").send_keys("samhith gardas")
  ```

---

However the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched[ng-model='applications']"))).send_keys("samhith gardas")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched' and @ng-model='applications']"))).send_keys("samhith gardas")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you @Debanjan B;. Will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-touched").
```

Or

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@claaa='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")
```

Class with space indicates multiple classes , so you have to replace space with dot in find_element_by_class

Else use xpath and find the element that matches absolute attribute value of the class